# Blender for Astroparticle Physics

Tags: python, animation, particles, physics

Hello Blender Community,

I work for the [Pierre Auger Observatory](https://auger.org), which is the worldwide largest detector system for ultra-high energetic cosmic rays, located in the Pampa Amarilla, Argentina. We are detecting extra-galactic particles arriving at earth with near light speed through the particle air showers developing from their interactions with the atmosphere. Unfortunately our visualizations for press and similar purposes are quite outdated (in my opinion), cf. [this animation](https://youtube.com/watch?v=cBgUHPyvjhU) .

Having heard that blender has a python interface I was hooked and wanted to try to visualize actual data (which we store python-accessible in HDF5 or ROOT format) with blender. After a few first steps I was not sure, if blender was the tool to go with, since (at least for me) the learning curve seems very steep and doing the visualization I wanted might not be possible in reasonable time. Also I could not find an important feature: particle creation within the animation (frankly speaking: having one particle, decaying into two particles along its track, which decay further, and so on).

My questions:
Can you estimate the required effort for a Blender beginner to create an animation similar to the one seen [here](https://youtu.be/bn_IgqAtwsc?t=217) from 3.37 to 4.02?
Is Blender capable of creating (in terms of multiplying) particles within the animation?
Is there an easy way to parse detector coordinates and signal values, so that the animation can depict actual data?

I am neither a spokesperson nor a task leader, so this request is very unofficial.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one *specific* question per post. This is so we can give a *specific* answer to it. Also, if the main question is the "Can you estimate" one then this would be a reason to close the question as there is no 'correct' answer, only people's opinions. The [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) provides some more information on this.